# iPhone: UISegmentedControl with custom images on pressed state

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a UISegmentedControl with some custom images:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] atIndex:2 animated:NO];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 30);
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];
```

This part works fine.  But, it still uses Apple's styling for the control and just adds my images over it.  Is there a way that I don't have to use Apple's styles, and customize the conrol with my own images with no background?  I would also like to have my own "selected" state images.

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

Nic,

After playing with this for a while, I decided to simply "roll my own" in a way.

I made some button images in photoshop and got everything looking like a segmented control.  Then, I set a different image for the "selected" states of all the buttons.  When one button was pressed, I called setSelected:NO to the others.  Then, I handled whatever I needed to do.

I'd love to hear other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DexterW's answer. I had came to same decision - to mimic `UISegmentedControl` using `UIButtons` only.
 
However its not a simple task to mimic `UISegmentControl`. I tried to use `Selected` state of a `UIButton` but `UIButton` wont work as expected if set same settings (bg image, font color) for `Hightlighted` and `Selected` states. In such case when segment looks selected its still "pressable" visually. So, to avoid it and make buttons set acting more like `UISegmentedControl` I didn't use a `selected` state at all. Instead Id decided to change appearance of selected button in code so that `normal` and `highlighted` states are the same visually for selected button and different for unselected one.
 
Assume I have 3 buttons segmentedControl (LeftSgm | MiddleSgm | RightSgm) and for normal state Im using bg picture named "segment_default" and font color white and for selected state its bg picture named "segment_active" and black font. So in onTouchDown:

```
-(IBAction)onTopMenuTap:(id)sender
{
    int newSelectedSegmentIndex;
    if (sender == btnLeftSgm)
        newSelectedSegmentIndex=0;
    else if (sender == btnMiddleSgm)
        newSelectedSegmentIndex=1;
    else if (sender == btnRightSgm)
        newSelectedSegmentIndex=2;
    else
        return;

    NSLog(@"Tapped segment index %d while old one is %d",newSelectedSegmentIndex,selectedSegmentIndex);

    if (newSelectedSegmentIndex==selectedSegmentIndex)
        return;

    [self handleSegmentAppearenace:newSelectedSegmentIndex];
//do whatever its need to be done
...
}
```

and the called method is

```
-(void)handleSegmentAppearenace:(int)newSelectedSegmentIndex
{
    if (selectedSegmentIndex==0){
        [btnLeftSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_default_left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnLeftSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnLeftSgm.highlighted = NO;
    }
    else if (selectedSegmentIndex==1){
        [btnMiddleSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_default_center"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnMiddleSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnMiddleSgm.highlighted = NO;
    }
    else if (selectedSegmentIndex==2){
        [btnRightSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_default_right"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnRightSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnRightSgm.highlighted = NO;
    }

    if (newSelectedSegmentIndex==0){
        [btnLeftSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_active_left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnLeftSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnLeftSgm.highlighted = YES;
    }
    else if (newSelectedSegmentIndex==1){
        [btnMiddleSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_active_center"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnMiddleSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnMiddleSgm.highlighted = YES;
    }
    else if (newSelectedSegmentIndex==2){
        [btnRightSgm setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_control_active_right"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnRightSgm setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnRightSgm.highlighted = YES;
    }
}
```

All three buttons are bound in IB to corresponding properties (btnRightSgm etc). Also for "touch up event" onTopMenuTap is bound.
Cant say its a best idea but it works perfectly for me.